# Laravel hasOneThrough or get relationship through intermediate table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Projects have a foreign key `client_id` with the `clients.id`

Clients have a foreign key `group_id` with `groups.id`

How can I access this relationship from the `Project` model such that I can get the group the project belongs to through the associated client?

I tried variations of the following:

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        'App\ClientGroup', // final table
        'App\Client', // intermediate table
        'group_id', // fk intermediate table
        'id', // fk final model
        // probably not right
        'client_id', 
        'id'
    );
}
```

NULL is returned when I try to access the relationship via:

```
Project::findOrFail(2)->group;
```

---

Projects:
[image]

Clients:
[image]

Groups:
[image]

Comment: The docs say it's `(FinalModel, IntermediateModel, Foreign key between this model and intermediate table, Foreign key between final model and intermediate model, primary key on final model, primary key on intermediate model)` so I would guess in your case it would be `(ClientGroup::class, Client::class, 'client_id', 'group_id', 'id', 'id')`. Your best chance to actually debug this is to do :  `Project::findOrFail(2)->group()->toSql()`

Comment: I've added my table schema. Your suggestion results in an error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clients.client_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `client_groups`.*, `clients`.`client_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `client_groups` inner join `clients` on `clients`.`id` = `client_groups`.`group_id` where `clients`.`deleted_at` is null and `clients`.`client_id` = 2 limit 1)"

Comment: Hi, Alex. How you try to get relation, if you doesn't get it from database? `Project::findOrFail(2)` returns you instance of `Project` model. If you want to get relation. You can do it with `Project::with('group')->findOrFail(2);` or `$group = Project::findOrFail(2)->group()->get();` or `$project = Project::findOrFail(2); $project->load('group');` . Try it and answer if it hepls you. Best wishes.

Comment: i believe what you are describing is eager loading, but laravel also supports lazy loading. for example, `Project::findOrFail(2)->client` gives me the related client model as that relationship is currently working. nevertheless, trying your method also returns NULL.